# Generating multiple rows of random arrays in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

For testing a database I'd like to generate a number of rows, each consisting of a set length array of random numbers. I can generate *n* rows of random numbers easily:

```
select round(random()*10) from generate_series(1,5);
```

and I can generate an array of random numbers:

```
select array(select round(random()*10) from generate_series(1,5));
```

but if I put them together the `array()` subquery only gets executed once:

```
select array(select round(random()*10) from generate_series(1,5)) from generate_series(1,5);

    array     
--------------
 {10,8,1,7,4}
 {10,8,1,7,4}
 {10,8,1,7,4}
 {10,8,1,7,4}
 {10,8,1,7,4}
(5 rows)
```

How do I get the subquery to run for each row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the function:

```
create or replace function random_int_array(int, int)
returns int[] language sql as
$$
    select array_agg(round(random()* $1)::int)
    from generate_series(1, $2)
$$;

select random_int_array(10, 5)
from generate_series(1, 5)

 random_int_array 
------------------
 {3,8,4,7,5}
 {0,10,3,5,4}
 {2,2,0,2,10}
 {8,1,4,3,9}
 {7,4,1,3,6}
(5 rows)
```

Note that the function should be volatile.

---

Update. Another approach, generate 25 random values and aggregate them in 5 groups:

```
select array_agg(round(random()* 10))
from generate_series(1, 25) i
group by i % 5
```

[db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=acd93e03cf22fd3dfda10c34de784fe7)

Comment: Thank you! That worked, and I learnt about volatile functions too!